# Update automatically imports in IntelliJ when the hierarchy changes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I have updated a library in a Java project, but the hierarchy of the classes has changed from the previous version. The name of the classes is the same, but they are located in a different path.

For example, in the previous version, I had:

```
import library.folder5.class1;
```

Now, I have something like:

```
import library.project4.module1.folder1.class1;
```

Is there any way of automatically update the paths of the imports?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

> Editor -> Auto import -> Optimize imports on the fly

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution, but it did not find the new path of the classes.

Comment: How actually you update the library, do you do it through intellij-idea? Because I am just guessing if you update the library with maven, for example, will it update the paths or not. I tried it with changing some library version with maven, but it didn't work out, intellij-idea didn't change anything, just showed that cannot resolve this path. So, then I needed to remove this import and only after that itellij helped me to import the proper class.

Comment: You are right, I am using Maven. Your solution obviously works, but it is still quite manual, I just wonder if there is a truly automatic way to update the paths.